# How to define a line as an algebraic variety in $\mathbb{A}^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have the complex plane $\mathbb{A}^2$. I want to describe any line passing through a point $p = (p_1, p_2), p_i \in \mathbb{C}$ as an affine algebraic variety. Such a line is described by $(\alpha, \beta)t + p$ where $(\alpha, \beta) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ and $t$ is a real number. The fact that $t$ must be a real number is messing me up.

My approach was to first describe this as $\mathbb{V}(\frac{X - p_1}{\alpha} - \frac{Y - p_2}{\beta}).$ However, we need both $\frac{X - p_1}{\alpha}, \frac{Y - p_2}{\beta}$ to be real numbers. I don't think it is possible to add this constraint by adding polynomials into our algebraic set. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: $\{(as+b,cs+d),s\in \Bbb{C}\}$ is the affine variety $V(c(z_1-b)-a(z_2-d))$ with coordinate ring $\Bbb{C}[z_1,z_2]/(c(z_1-b)-a(z_2-d))$

Comment: By line they don't mean an affine *real* $1$-dimensional subspace. If you're working over a field $k$ (in this case $\Bbb C$), it's an affine $1$-dimensional subspace over $k$. In particular, describe the line as the solution set of an equation rather than parametrically.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot more sense. Thank you.